# the color I'm using on illustrator appears different when I save the image to use on my website

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, color, export, rgb

I'm doing a website and now I received the logo they want to use in website.

The logo is in Illustrator format and I´m having a problem with this logo.

In illustrator he has the color #2e3182, which seems to be a kind of purple.

To save this logo to use on my website, I went to:

Edit->Assign profile->Don´t color Manage this Document

And then File->Save for web, and I saved as Gif.

The result Im having is what you can see in my two images below, in illustrator logo color is a kind a purple (#2e3182), but in website color appears different, the color in website is appearing like blue.

Do you know why this can be hapen

Illustrator color:

[image]

Website Color:

[image]

Comment: Neither of those colors are #2E3182, but the second one is closer to it (#2E3284). Is your document in RGB mode?

Comment: yeah I also believe that you're working on a cmyk document and/or use some settings for the gif that change that

Comment: And why on earth would you *not* color manage the document?

Comment: colors are not numbers, and may render as different numbers dependimg on how things get color corrected. By the way theres no such thing as no color correction. Disabling color correction is guaranteed to give random results. Web imagers usually assume sRGB

Answer (score 1):

Much like the others have stated, the default color mode for AI is CMYK.  Unless you tell it otherwise, your image will be exported in CMYK (not sure why you wouldn't want to color manage it), so you need to change your color mode to RGB via the File menu (as pictured below) then color your artwork accordingly.

[image: RGB]